# Regex Help - Need to add optional comma seperation to already existing regex

Tags: regex

This is the regex that I have made

```
/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+/
```

what it does is validates weather a range of numbers is chosen (eg: 1-2 or 4-7)

now I want to add comma separation to this regex such that it accepts strings like (1-2,3-4,... and even 1-2)

I tried doing something like:

```
/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+(,[0-9]+-[0-9]+)/
```

But this matches only things like 1-2,3-4 and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close on this. Use `?:` for an optional match, like so:

```
[0-9]+-[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+-[0-9]+)*
```

Comment: Thank you!!, I was so close to the solution. thank you for helping me out!!